# Question about parameters in a boolean statement

Tags: java

So I have this question for a Java class I am taking. It is very simple and maybe I am just missing something simple but I can't seem to figure out how to do this:

*Code and test a boolean expression that returns true if an integer variable “n” is in the range -15 to 50 inclusive but not odd in the range 10 to 20 inclusive.*

The method I have been trying is this:

```
System.out.println(n%2==0 && n > 10 && n < 20 && n>-15 && n < 50);
```

While it does the non-odd number and 10-20 inclusivity correctly it will not state that a value is "true" when outside of the 10-20 range.

p.s question requires this to be done in a *sout* line

Comment: you are very close, since this is an assignment the community will guide you instead of providing a straight answer. Hint 1 : what does `n%2==0` do?

Comment: Aha it's not really an assignment anymore, this question was for homework months ago but I am just revising for an upcoming exam.

Anyways, n%2==0 is basically just checking whether the value "n" is  equal to 0 or not (checking if even or odd)

Comment: correct, how does it help you solve the question? Hint 2 : have you tried using the `!` ( not ) operator somewhere?

Comment: infact a better hint would be : can you write those conditions separately first?

Comment: It is only needed when the value is between 10 & 20 as the value will only be true between those values when it is even. Initially, I had it as != but I changed it to == because it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using parentheses helps to better represent your condition, which I've reproduced here, annotated on what I believe to be the correct solution.

```
System.out.println(        // true if an integer variable “n” is 
    n >= -15 && n <= 50        // in the range -15 to 50 inclusive 
    && !(                      // but not 
        n % 2 == 1             // odd 
        && n >= 10 && n <= 20  // in the range 10 to 20 inclusive.
    )
);
```

note that I use `>=` and `<=`, rather than `>` and `<`, because it says "inclusive".

I don't think it's possible to represent this expression in a single line without using some parentheses to group some of the checks together.